# How do you use custom IPv4 headers in K6?

Tags: javascript, go, kubernetes, k6

Is it possible to use custom [IPv4 headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#/media/File:IPv4_Packet-en.svg) in the [K6](https://k6.io) load testing framework from Grafana?

For example, I'd like to be able to set the options field in the IPv4 header or change the TTL.

I've looked into using [Scapy](https://scapy.net/) and [Gopacket](https://github.com/google/gopacket), but a higher level framework made for load testing K8s would be very helpful because I won't have to implement those features.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with standard k6.